# Nexus 6 Kernel Build Error

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Working on building the Nexus 6 kernel (Source: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git) under the android-msm-shamu-3.10-lollipop-mr1 branch. I am using the arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 toolchain.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
  CC      drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.o
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c: In function 'dhd_watchdog_thread':
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:2978:47: error: 'MAX_RT_PRIO' undeclared (first use in this function)
   param.sched_priority = (dhd_watchdog_prio < MAX_RT_PRIO)?
                                               ^
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:2978:47: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c: In function 'dhd_dpc_thread':
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:3095:42: error: 'MAX_RT_PRIO' undeclared (first use in this function)
   param.sched_priority = (dhd_dpc_prio < MAX_RT_PRIO)?dhd_dpc_prio:(MAX_RT_PRIO-1);
                                          ^
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c: In function 'dhd_rxf_thread':
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:3156:42: error: 'MAX_RT_PRIO' undeclared (first use in this function)
   param.sched_priority = (dhd_rxf_prio < MAX_RT_PRIO)?dhd_rxf_prio:(MAX_RT_PRIO-1);
                                          ^
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:3160:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'daemonize' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  DAEMONIZE("dhd_rxf");
  ^
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c: In function 'dhd_preinit_ioctls':
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:5354:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'srandom32' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   SRANDOM32((uint)jiffies);
   ^
drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.c:5355:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'random32' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   rand_mac = RANDOM32();
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/dhd_linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

From some research, it appears that random32 and srandom32 are from an older kernel (~3.6). So I used Grub to boot into an older kernel version. However, the make must still be running the newer (3.16) kernel's libraries as I've received the same errors.

I edited the makefile to include the 'include' directory of the 3.06 headers file, but that didn't fix the issue either. How can I force make to use these old libraries instead of the new ones. And why is it that I need to go to an old kernel to build the Nexus 6 kernel? I built the Nexus 4 kernel before with out any problems and that was an older phone..

Comment: The kernel that you're running on your host system is irrelevant. When you're building the Linux kernel for an embedded device, you should be working inside of or near a Linux kernel source code tree of whatever version of the kernel you want to build. That tree should have its own include folder -- referencing your system's include folders is not correct.

Comment: I think I understand. So the official msm source for the nexus 6 branch is buggy then? I see that it does have its own include folder, but, for example, its linux/random.h file is missing those srandom32 and random32 functions which explains my errors. Wouldn't that be a pretty glaring error they would have fixed in order to compile their own kernel?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure those sources should work just fine. What commands are you running to configure the kernel and then to start the build?

Comment: Here are the exact commands I run (after I make sure to export the toolchain to my path variable. Note: I've used pretty much every toolchain I could get my hands on so I don't think that's the issue.):

Comment: mkdir ~/msm  ||  cd msm  ||  git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git  ||  cd msm  ||  git checkout -t remotes/origin/android-msm-shamu-3.10-lollipop-mr1

Comment: make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- shamu_defconfig  ||  make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-

Comment: The only significant issue I see is that the Google docs recommend reversing the order of things a little.
export ARCH=arm &&
export SUBARCH=arm &&
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- &&
make shamu_defconfig &&
make;
instead of treating those as arguments for make. And you say you've tried different toolchains, so this probably isn't it, but the Google docs do also recommend "arm-eabi-", not "arm-linux-androideabi-".

If I get time to work on it later today and I remember, I may see if I can get the Nexus 6 kernel to build on my own computer. Everything says it should work just fine.

Comment: I tried those commands with the arm-eabi-4.6 and arm-eabi-4.8 toolchains but to no avail. Thank you so much for looking into this! I'm befuddled as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So I started from scratch and reinstalled everything and it worked... I guess when I was working on the nexus 4 kernel I didn't switch branches properly and maybe that had something to do with my issues. Thank you again for all of the help!

Comment: No problem! Sorry I forgot to look at this last night, but I'm glad it's working for you now.